# Modelling a Pizza

Tags: oop, uml, modeling

I'm trying to create a food ordering application. It will recieve menu data from a webservice (format not yet decided), and turn it into an order form.

I'm having trouble working out how to approach pizzas - they are more complicated than anything else as you can choose the size, base, toppings etc.

I want to have a class of Product, which I can create for each item in the menu. Then, this product will be given objects of class Size and Option. This allows a pizza to be created, its size set (e.g. regular/large/xl) and a set of toppings (Option) to be set.

I need, somehow, for the Option objects to know what the Size of the Product is. I need to do this, as a topping may cost £5 for a regular pizza, but the same topping cost £7 for a large one. Ideally, Option wouldn't be an element of Size, as the options available stay the same for each size - only the price changes.

My (probably wrong) model looks like this: http://yuml.me/diagram/scruffy/class/%5BPizza%5D-%3E%5BToppings%5D,%20%5BPizza%5D-%3E%5BSize%5D

Any ideas on how I could achieve this?

Comment: Why wouldn't you make **size** one of the properties of **Product** class?

Comment: It really depends what you want to do with the Pizza.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the [Decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) as a starting point.

A base Pizza class will have properties and methods for adding sauces, toppings, etc. Decorators can modify the size of the base Pizza. For example, an ExtraLargePizza decorator will change the size. Each decorator should expose the functionality for calculating the cost of the pizza. This is because the decorator knows its own size.

Comment: That looks very interesting, and I can understand how that'd work. I'm certainly going to give this method a go. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Having actually written software to deal with this, I found having sub-items to represent options worked best. In essence, allow items to have sets of sub-items, and then those sub-items can have sets of more sub-items, etc. Each option is really an just another item (it's got a name and a price), only it's related to another item. So in your example, it might look like this:

```
Pizza (Item)
|--> Size (ItemSet)
|      |--> Large ($15) (Item)
|      |      |--> Toppings (ItemSet)
|      |             |--> Pepperoni ($7) (Item)
|      |             |--> Anchovies ($7) (Item)
|      |--> Regular ($10) (Item)
|             |--> Toppings (ItemSet)
|                    |--> Pepperoni ($4) (Item)
|                    |--> Anchovies ($4) (Item)
|--> Crust (ItemSet)
       |--> Thin (Item)
       |--> Deep-Dish (Item)
```

The Pizza item has a Size itemset, which contains 2 items (large or regular), each of which has their own Toppings itemset, which contains the list of toppings for each, each with their own pricing. You can have multiple itemsets per item (and most likely would need them). I showed this with the crust itemset. Sub-items don't have to have pricing of their own. Generally pricing is additive, so the top-level item (pizza) usually has the base price, and then sub-items selected have their price added onto the base price as the user selects them.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I don't want to do it this way if possible, though I may have to. I'm going to give the decorator pattern a go first.